# What benefit is there to using LiveData when all data is provided by direct user input at runtime?

Tags: android, database, android-room, android-livedata

One of the major benefits of LiveData is its 'lifecycle awareness'. However, if an app relies solely on direct user inputted data which can only be inputted when the app is in an active state (or in other words when never be updated when the app isn't in an inactive state), is there actually any point or benefit to using LiveData?

For clarity's sake here's an 'outline' example of an app which I think might not benefit from LiveData:

The app plots a simple line graphs of values over time. The coordinates are based on the value inputted by the user and the time is set to the time of input. The data is persisted in a Room database and is displayed according to regular periods (let's say weekly). These weekly graphs are displayed on the UI as individual views in a scrollable RecyclerView. Furthermore, when the user inputs a value, that input is immediately translated and displayed on the UI's graph widget for the current week.

Answer (score 0):

LiveData is **Observable data holder** class with **life cycle awareness**.

So update to date data and observer pattern are the benefits of using LiveData, even though data coming from user input.

1.Even though you are updating data from user input, we have configuration changes,Live data always gives to updated data.

2.One main advantage is it uses Observer pattern, so your observer updates UI, we don't need to change UI every time data changes.

Comment: But with a simple design like this where there will essentially only be one Observer it seems superfluous to put this architecture in place no? The end result is the same but the code becomes somewhat less readable? The flow would either be data to database and to widget from input view (without using LiveData) or to database from input view then database to widget (using LiveData). Unless I'm misunderstanding something that is?

Comment: In the case of user runtime user input that is. Previously stored data can be obtained directly from the database

Comment: Yes for simple design like this, we don't need a new library itself. But i think  by using this library code becomes more readable, manageable. and you can scale easily when problem becomes complex.